# All the cakes less than group by sum

Tags: sql, group-by

I have the following sql diagram:

```
Category:
id_category
category_name

Measurement
id_measurement
name_measurement

Ingredient
id_ingredient
name_ingredient
category_id
measurement_id
nrOfCal

IngredientCake
id_ingredient
cake_code
quantities

Cake
cake_code
cake_name
```

I don't know how to display all the code and name cakes that have less than 500 calories.
What I've tried:

```
select [Cake].cake_code , [Cake].cake_name 
from       [Cake] 
inner join [Ingredient_Cake] 
on         ([Cake].cake_code = [Ingredient_Cake].cake_code)
inner join [Ingredient] 
on         ([Ingredient_Cake].id_ingredient = [Ingredient].id_ingredient)
where      sum([Ingredient].nrOfCal) < 500 
group by   [Cake].cake_code;
```

but anyway it gives me the error:

```
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.
```

Any solution?

EDIT:

```
 select     [Cake].cake_code, 
       [Cake].cake_name 
 from       [Cake] 
 inner join [Ingredient_Cake] 
 on         ([Cake].cake_code = [Ingredient_Cake].cake_code)
 inner join [Ingredient] 
 on         ([Ingredient_Cake].id_ingredient = [Ingredient].id_ingredient)
 group by   [Cake].cake_code, [Cake].cake_name
 having     sum(nrOfCal*quantities) > 500;
```

I ve edited and now the funny part is that if I let it that way, it returns me how it should, the cakes with the calories lower than 500 but the condition now is (>500), and if I change the condition to < 500, it only returns me the cake that has more than 500 calories. What's going on?

Comment: try by moving it to the `having` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move the aggregate to the having clause:

```
select     [Cake].cake_code, 
           [Cake].cake_name 
from       [Cake] 
inner join [Ingredient_Cake] 
on         ([Cake].cake_code = [Ingredient_Cake].cake_code)
inner join [Ingredient] 
on         ([Ingredient_Cake].id_ingredient = [Ingredient].id_ingredient)
group by   [Cake].cake_code, [Cake].cake_name
having     sum([Ingredient].nrOfCal) < 500;
```

Comment: I don't know your data, maybe you should multiply IngredientCake.quantities by nrOfCal?

Answer (score 0):

Since your condition is on aggregated values , you'll need to use `HAVING` clause (executed after `group by`) instead of `where`:

```
select [Cake].cake_code , [Cake].cake_name from [Cake] 
inner join [Ingredient_Cake] on ([Cake].cake_code = 
[Ingredient_Cake].cake_code)
inner join [Ingredient] on ([Ingredient_Cake].id_ingredient 
= [Ingredient].id_ingredient)
group by [Cake].cake_code
Having sum([Ingredient].nrOfCal) < 500
```